# Reusable component using ngOnInit

Tags: angular, components

I'm trying to make a reusable component but I can't find a way to make ngOnInit get the data depends on the component input.

Service :

```
export class BookService {
  private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  getBooks(): Observable<DragItem[]> {
    return this.http.get<DragItem[]>(this.apiUrl + 'books');
  }
  getNames(): Observable<DragItem[]> {
    return this.http.get<DragItem[]>(this.apiUrl + 'names');
  }
}
```

the component :

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.booksService
      .getBooks() // => how can I make this dynamic depends on component props so I can pick (getBooks / getNames)
      .subscribe((response) => (this.items = response));
  }
```

Comment: you can use `@Input` to give a "property" from parent:https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs#sending-data-to-a-child-component, or if you're using directly in router using router data: https://angular.io/api/router/Route#data or a parameter:https://angular.io/guide/router#getting-route-information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by changing the service to one method

service :

```
export class BookService {
  private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getData(str: string): Observable<DragItem[]> {
    return this.http.get<DragItem[]>(this.apiUrl + str);
  }
}
```

component :

```
  @Input() type: string = '';
  @Input() methodName = '';
  items: DragItem[] = [];
  selectedItems: DragItem[] = [];
  searchInput = new FormControl('');
  page: number = 1;
  pageSize: number = 10;

  constructor(private booksService: BookService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.booksService
      .getData(this.methodName)
      .subscribe((response: DragItem[]) => (this.items = response));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use @Input/Suscriber/localstorage in the component to get which method you want to call dynamic method. I assume you already have the name of dynamic method, you can call it like this:

```
public methodName: string = "Assign your method name dynamically to it"
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.booksService[`${methodName}`]() 
      .subscribe((response) => (this.items = response));
  }
```

Comment: Looks like worked but now I'm stuck in type error :(

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'BookService

Comment: I suggest you to ask a new question on it as it will be easy for other users to follow the question and implement it.

Comment: If the question helped you to resolve the issue you mentioned, please accept and upvote it. Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular's dependency providers to achieve your goal.
Check details: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#specifying-an-alternative-class-provider

First of all we need base service:

```js
export abstract class DataItemsService {
    abstract fetch(): Observable<DataItem[]>;
}
```

This service needs to be injected to your reusable component:

```js
export class FeatureComponent implements OnInit {

    dataItems$: Observable<DataItem[]>;

    constructor(private readonly dataItemsService: DataItemsService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.dataItems$ = this.dataItemsService.fetch();
    }
}
```

Then implement any services you need:

```js
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BookService implements DataItemsService {
    fetch(): Observable<DataItem[]> {
        return of([{value: 'book1'}, {value: 'book2'}]);
    }
}

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NamesService implements DataItemsService {
    fetch(): Observable<DataItem[]> {
        return of([{value: 'name1'}, {value: 'name2'}]);
    }
}
```

The only left is to specify the desired service in providers list of the parent component.

Using BookService:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-demo1',
    template: `
        <app-feature></app-feature>
    `,
    providers: [
        { provide: DataItemsService, useClass: BookService },
    ],
})
export class Demo1Component {}
```

Using NameService:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-demo1',
    template: `
        <app-feature></app-feature>
    `,
    providers: [
        { provide: DataItemsService, useClass: NamesService },
    ],
})
export class Demo1Component {}
```

Comment: My component was something like this, the problem is when you want to reuse this component in something new (not books or names ) you need to add code to the component

Comment: Ok, I'll provide more generic solution.